# Screen jumping around when some DOM elements get removed (React)

Tags: css, reactjs

So I have the following problem with my website:

Let's say I have 5 posts, post A, B, C, D and E, and that every post has a width of about 80 vh.

Now, let's say I scroll down so that post C is visible on my website, and, while I am still on post C, posts A and B get removed from the DOM. Now, what happens is, since posts A and B are no longer there, posts C, D and E move up to fill the empty space left by the deletion of posts A and B, while my screen stays in place, and now after this behavior post E is displayed on my screen.

This is not what I want. I want to make it so that after removing posts A and B, maybe the viewport reduces its height from the top down or something similar, and my screen remains on post C.

Is there any way to force this behavior using some React magic or by editing the CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Not really,
when the elements are removed from the DOM, it pushes the posts up as your elements probably have position: relative. you can use position: absolute to keep them in specific location, but that will not remove the empty new space created after removing the elements. and doesn't seem to be a good option.

What i can suggest as having some kind of a div that takes let's say 80vh and inside this div all the posts with some kind of overflow scroll. and then you are not scrolling the page but the div.

Comment: This crossed my mind as well but I am not sure if I will be able to fix it this way. WIll give it a try when I have the time.